# switching branches keeps new files from other branch

Tags: git

Sometimes if I add and commit new files to branch A and then switch to branch B the new files are marked as untracked in branch B.

These files do not exist in branch B and I believe they shouldn't appear as untracked after I switch.

I'm on Windows so I'm guessing that it may be because another process (Eclipse) is holding on to these files so git cannot remove them from my working copy when switching??

Comment: can you post some `git` output? like `git status` before and after the commit or switch? the content of `.gitignore` in each branch?

Comment: Interesting it could have been that the .gitignore is different between 2 branches and these ingored files is what I was seeing.. I'll see if it happens again over the next couple of days. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking: you `git add`'ed but the files were ignored, then switched branches but the new branch wasn't ignoring them, so they got listed as untracked.